# How to set tab indentation settings in a project in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have my tab indentation settings set to tabs with a tab width of 4 spaces.

However, when I open up a React Native project in Xcode, it overrides my settings with an indentation of 2 spaces.

How do you change the settings back to mine in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode's Text Editing preferences is where you set the indentation settings. Choose Xcode > Preferences to access Xcode's preferences.

[image]